# How can I prevent rkhunter from always giving me the same warnings?

Tags: rkhunter

I get these warnings every single day from Rootkit Hunter:

```
---------------------- Start Rootkit Hunter Scan ----------------------
Warning: Package manager verification has failed:
         File: /usr/sbin/tcpd
         The file permissions have changed
Warning: Package manager verification has failed:
         File: /usr/bin/less
         The symbolic link target has changed
Warning: Package manager verification has failed:
         File: /usr/bin/telnet
         The file permissions have changed

----------------------- End Rootkit Hunter Scan -----------------------
```

And yes :-) I have run `rkhunter --propupd` before and after this problem started. No change, still get these warnings every day. Why and how can I stop them?

Comment: The question should rather be: Why do these files change on a daily basis?

Comment: As far as I know, they don't. To be sure I've checked all three, and taken a screen shot to see if they are different tomorrow.